# C# NLua: Accessing generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, arguments, monogame, nlua

I have an Entity component system using generic parameters. I am trying to get Lua scripting to work using NLua.

However I do not know how to access a generic parameter from the Lua environment.

Something like this?:

```
if e:HasComponent<Position>() then
    print("Found position...")
end
```

If there is no way to do this then how would I go about making the components accessible via strings?

Code snippets will be given on request as I do not think it is a problem with my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to call the Generic method directly, without the type parameter, NLua will try to match the method name.

```
if e:HasComponent () then
    ...
end
```

If it fails you can also try to wrap you generic method into a non-generic extension method.

```
public static HasPositionComponent (this TypeE e)
{
     return e.HasComponent<Position>();
}
```

Then you can call HasPositionComponent as a regular method from Lua

```
if e:HasPositionComponent () then
    ...
end
```

Take a look at the GenericMethod test:

https://github.com/NLua/NLua/blob/main/tests/src/LuaTests.cs#L442